# Magento special price spacing is off, but where?

Tags: magento

if you look at this page from the magento demo:

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/pivot-table-excel.html

you should see that the label "Special Price" is just slightly indented compared to "Regular Price" label above it.

i'm normally good at finding and fixing issues like this but I've been tearing my hair out trying to get rid of that tiny indent. can anyone help?

what I want is for both labels aligned left with no indent. thanks!

Comment: There isn't any indenting.  Use firebug or chrome's inspector and you can see for yourself.

Comment: thanks for looking but there is padding or margin or something coming from somewhere. I've used firebug a lot to diagnose this and you can see the additional space there when firebug highlights the element. you can also visually see it cross browser, and I've even taken a screen grab and checked in photoshop. there is definitely 2-3px of space there that shouldn't be... totally lost as to what is causing it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the font face itself, nothing to do with the CSS or markup.  Kill the font deceleration in the body tag and you'll see.  Arial has some weird kerning at times. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning

Comment: thanks, I hate stuff like that. I wanted to change the wording anyway and luckily the new wording aligns properly.